# Angular + Selenium Setting model backed values

Tags: jquery, angularjs, selenium

I have a DOM input element backed by ng-model='obj.values.x.value'
`obj.values.x.value` has a value, say "foo".

when running the code in Selenium the field says "foo".
I try to set the field to an empty string via `element.clear()`
calling `element.getAttribute("value")` still returns "foo";

if I use JQuery to get the dom element and then call `$(element).focus(); $(element).val('');` `$(element).blur();`
calling `element.getAttribute("value")` still returns "foo";

without knowing that angular has bound the ng-model to `obj.values.x.value`, is there anyway from Selenium to set the value of the element so that the default value from the model is changed?

Further tests show that this error only occurs when there is a default value provided in the model and we try to set the value to an empty string.

Comment: The issue appears to be that AngularJS intercepts the changes to the input element and that selenium does the same but perhaps at a different point in the process.  I think that the AngularJS does not see any changes when a null length string is passed.  I just need a way to tell AngularJS that the value has changed so that it will change the Model value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you're erasing the value. Try the following with jQuery:

```
$(element).val('');
```

Not too familiar with Selenium, but jQuery [`empty` removes child nodes](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), not the contents of the input.

Comment: this solution does not work.  The issue seems to be that AngularJS resets the value to the value that is in the model, rather than setting the value in the model to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because whenever you change the value of any model in Angular app from outside, it doesn't digest that. for that we need to use $scope.apply(); I hope it make sense.